# Sitefinity Word 2003 - Can you create Blog Entries

Tags: sitefinity

I know you can use Word2007 to create Blog Posts for Sitefinity, but does anyone know if you can do this in Word2003?  Other there any other options to have an defined end user be able to create/modify a blog post without have to use Sitefinity's admin tools?

Thanks,

R

Answer (score 0):

Sitefinity supports the [Metablog API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetaWeblog) and you can edit/create blog posts with any tool that also has support for that API. Gabe Sumner wrote a post a while ago about how to set up Windows Live Writer with Sitefinity Blogs. Check it out: [Blogging with ease using Sitefinity & Windows Live Writer](http://blogs.telerik.com/gabesumner/posts/08-10-03/blogging_with_ease_using_sitefinity_amp_windows_live_writer.aspx)